# How to add a css class to MVCContrib grid <th>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I tried:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.PagedList).Columns(column =>{
    column.For(m => m.Name).Attributes(@class => "test");
})
```

But that just added it to the  tag inside the grid.

Comment: Found the answer to my own question. I had to HeaderAttributes, not Attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `HeaderAttributes`:

```
column
    .For(m => m.Name)
    .Attributes(@class => "test")
    .HeaderAttributes(@class => "someheaderclass");
```

Answer (score 1):

While your solution is more suitable in this context, you could use more general approach with jQuery adding this line somewhere in JavaScript code below:

```
$('th').addClass("test");
```